# How to convert Parallel.For to PLINQ

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, plinq

```
Parallel.For(0, Height, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 6 }, y =>
{
    int currentLine = y * BMPData.Stride;

    for (int x = 0; x < Width; x = x + BPX)
    {
        var b = pixels[currentLine + x];
        var g = pixels[currentLine + x + 1];
        var r = pixels[currentLine + x + 2];

        int avg = (r + g + b) / 3;
        pixels[currentLine + x] = (byte)avg;
        pixels[currentLine + x + 1] = (byte)avg;
        pixels[currentLine + x + 2] = (byte)avg;
    }
});
```

This is basically a parallel code where it turns bitmap data pixels into gray ones, but is there any way I can replace the `Parallel.For` usage with Parallel Linq? I know there's no point to this, but it's required for a certain assignment

Comment: There is a [whitepaper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/C/F/BCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D/WhenToUseParallelForEachOrPLINQ.pdf) which was written a decade ago, but it contains a lot of valuable information when to use which.

Comment: There *is* a point to this - it's easier to parallelize problems that don't modify shared state, which would require locking. With PLINQ you can produce a *new* array with averaged colors without. modifying the original. There are some very significant improvements you can perform too - graphics transformations are so common that CPUs have operations to accelerate them (eg SIMD, SSE, AVX) by processing multiple values at the same time

Comment: For example you can use [Vector3.Addition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3.op_addition?view=net-5.0#System_Numerics_Vector3_op_Addition_System_Numerics_Vector3_System_Numerics_Vector3_) to add the values of *three rows* at a time, then divide each element with [Vector3 division](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3.op_division?view=net-5.0#System_Numerics_Vector3_op_Division_System_Numerics_Vector3_System_Single_). Eg: `var vR=new Vector3(pixels[x,y1],pixels[x,y2],pixels[y3]);...; var vAvg=(vR+vG_vB)/3;` to get avg for 3 lines

Comment: I think you could eliminate the 2nd for loop by using `Parallel.For(0, Width * Height / BPX, ...)` and `currentLine + x` would just become `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Range`, and `ForAll` to get similar results. Although note `ForAll` will not process the list in any stable order - which is probably fine for your use case

```
Enumerable.Range(0,Height)
          .AsParallel()
          .WithDegreeOfParallelism(6)
          .ForAll(y => 
{
   /// existing code here
});
```

Comment: Instead of `Enumerable.Range(0, Height).AsParallel()`, an equivalent alternative is: `ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, Height)`

Comment: .AsOrdered() and .AsSequential() could be used, if needed,

Comment: @tymtam AFAIK the `AsOrdered` has no effect on the [`ForAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.forall) operator. It only affects the single-thread enumeration of the resulting `ParallelQuery<T>`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias [Introduction to PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq#ordered-versus-unordered-parallel-queries) states: *An AsOrdered sequence is still processed in parallel, but its results are buffered and sorted.*

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thanks - I didn't know about `ParallelEumerable`

Comment: @tymtam so you say that the `AsOrdered` operator affects the `ForAll` operator somehow? How exactly? The `ForAll` method executes the supplied action for each element in parallel. The concept of order is meaningful only when things are happening sequentially.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias There is the order of reassembling the results and the order of picking up the next tasks to work on. *An AsOrdered sequence is still processed in parallel, but its results are buffered and sorted.*

Comment: @tymtam yeap, but the `ForAll` is a `void` returning method. Is has no results. So how is it related to `AsOrdered`?

Comment: `AsOrdered` has no meaningful effect on `ForAll` - https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Q9Oqa

Answer (score -1):

[The ForAll Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq#the-forall-operator) paragraph in the Introduction to PLINQ article has a ForAll example and ForAll seems to be perfect for what you do.
This example could be modified to your case

```
var nums = Enumerable.Range(0, Height);
var query =
    from num in nums.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(6)
    select num;

// Process the results as each thread completes
query.ForAll(e => MakeGray(e));
```

where MakeGray is your pixel setting method.

This doesn't do any better than Jamiec's answer, but has some more fluff which may or may not be what you're looking for.

---

BTW. I think you could eliminate the 2nd for loop by using

`Parallel.For(0, Width * Height / BPX, ...)`

or

`Enumerable.Range(0, Width * Height / BPX).AsParallel()...`

and `currentLine + x` would just become `x`.

Comment: Eliminating the second loop will surely affect negatively the performance. When doing parallel work, you don't want to make the workload too granular.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Agreed, but the OP stated it's for an assignment, so I treat this academically.